# Reading two matrices from the same file in java

Tags: java, arrays

Hello guys and thank you in advance for your help! 
I am trying to do a matrice calculator in java 
that reads two matrices from the same file like this: 
2 2 
34 78 
89 -12 
@ 
2 2 
67 76 
123 5

first line is the rank 
second and third line are the first matrix 
the "@" splits the first and the second matrix

and that's the code I came up with and I didn't 
find anything similar to this problem... can someone help me please?

```
String [] line = new String[30];
    int counter = 2;
    int rank[] = new int[2];
    int matrixa[][] = new int [3][3];

    try {

        BufferedReader MyReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("matrix.txt"));

        while(line != null) {
            line = MyReader.readLine().split(" ");
        }

        rank[0] = Integer.parseInt(line[0]);
        rank[1] = Integer.parseInt(line[1]);

        for(int i = 0; i <rank[0];i++) {
            for (int j=0;j<rank[1];j++) {
                matrixa[i][j] = Integer.parseInt(line[counter]);
                counter++;
                System.out.print(matrixa[i][j] + " ");
            }
            System.out.println();
        } }catch (Exception e) {}
```

Comment: Please read [mcve] and enhance your question accordingly. "doesn't work" isn't a working problem description.

Comment: Again: what exactly is not working? Don't expect people to download your source code, compile and run it to understand where it deviates from your requirements.

Comment: my main problem is to read the second matrix when the reader reaches the symbol @ it crashes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Leaving a ticker variable at when your lines is equal to "@"

```
int ticker;
for(int i = 0; i < lines.length; i++){
    if(lines[i].equals("@")) ticker = i;
}
```

This ticker then can be used to break the array. This could also be used earlier to break up the array into 2 separate arrays if that is expected.

```
String currentLine;
String[] line  = new String[15];
String[] line2 = new String[15];
int i = 0;
while(line != null && !currentLine.equals("@")){
    line = MyReader.readLine().split("");
    currentLine = line[i];
    if(currentLine.equals("@")) line[i] = null;
    i++;
}
while(line2 != null)){
    line2 = MyReader.readLine().split("");
}
```

They can be parsed into matrices and then math can be done on them from there.
Best of luck with your endeavors.